# What are the chances of breaking a stick into two pieces?

Tags: combinatorics, geometric-probability

We randomly break a 2 meters long stick into 2 pieces.

A. Probability of the event "one piece is longer than 120 cm"? //edited 
B. If we know both pieces are shorter than 150 cms, then what is chance of event A (One of the pieces is longer than 120 cms) ? 
C. Are B and A independent from each other?

I think i misunderstood the question.
My opinion for  
A. 80/200? 
B. 120/150?

Comment: opinion based on what reason? why that opinion and not the other?

Comment: EDIT : Deleted erroneous post

Comment: Oops. You're right - sorry.

Comment: @bof, since the stick is broken randomly, would't it be reasonable to assume a uniform distribution for the length of either stick?

Comment: @bof you are right, sorry my English is not the best.

Comment: If $X$ is the length of the longer piece, then $X$ takes values in the interval $(100,200).$ Event $A$ is $X\gt120.$ Assuming a uniform distribution (was that given?) the probability of $A$ is $80/100.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of we find the chance of occurrence of event $A$ -

That is, either stick has a length of $120\,cm$ or more. Consider stick 1.

Then, the probability that the stick has a length between a particular interval would be proportional to the length of that interval (as the stick has no restrictions on the value of its length.

So, $P(A \,for \,stick1)$ = $\dfrac {(200-120)}{200}$ = $\dfrac 25$;

However, the stick satisfying event $A$ might as well have been stick 2.
Therefore, $P(A) = 2.\dfrac 25 = \dfrac 45$.

For event $B$, that is, probability that both sticks have a length lesser while also satisfying event $A$ simply means either one stick must have a length between $120\,cm$ to $150\,cm$. Can you figure this out?

EDIT : As mentioned in the comments, $P(B) = \dfrac 3{10}$.

So now, to check for independence, we compare $P(A).P(B)$ with $P(A\cap B)$.However, $A\cap B$ simply represents $B$, from definition.

Comment: so P(B) it can be 1-(150-50/200)=1-1/2= 1/2    

or with your train of thought  
(200-150)/200= 1/4 but cause of 2 sticks its 2*1/4 = 1/2 am i right? please correct me if im not.

Comment: The chance of event $B$ would be $P(B) = 2.\dfrac {(150-120)}{200} = \dfrac 3{10}$, following the same reasoning as before.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, i meant only P(150) without A.

P(B) is 3/10.